# Automatically convert a String to a dynamically determined type?

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I am doing a bit of manual deserialization of an xml file. I need to convert all the values in the xml file (which are Strings) into the proper types.

I am getting the proper type by matching the name of the xml tag to a `Field` in my object via reflection.

Right now, the code I am using is a bit ugly:

```
Field matchedField = getMatchingField(getNodeName(node));
Class<?> type = matchedField.getType();

if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
{
    return Integer.parseInt(parseNode(node));
}
else if (Double.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
{
    return Double.parseDouble(parseNode(node));
}
else if // ... etc for all the types I am using
```

Is there a way to automate this process? Something like:

```
return ConvertToType(type, parseNode(node));
```

It seems that C# has something like this, does Java have a similar utility?

It isn't a requirement that this has to be extensible for custom Types. I can do the conversion for custom Types manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in facility for that, but you can definitely avoid the chain of `if`s by employing an interface and a map that maps types to converters.

The following code sets up the map:

```
// This interface defines the conversion method
interface Converter {
    Object fromString(String s);
}
// This map has one converter per supported class
static final Map<Class,Converter> mapper = new HashMap<Class,Converter>();
static {
    mapper.put(Integer.class, new Converter() {
        public Object fromString(String s) {
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
    });
    mapper.put(Double.class, new Converter() {
        public Object fromString(String s) {
            return Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
    });
}
```

Once the map is set up, you can do conversions like this:

```
int x = (int)mapper.get(Integer.class).fromString("123");
double y = (double)mapper.get(Double.class).fromString("1.23");
```

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/plt3aU)